# Compression with gzip to be used in LaNet-vi

Tags: ubuntu, gzip

I am trying to submit a network file to [LaNet-vi](http://lanet-vi.fi.uba.ar/lanetvi.php). The site requires that the file be gzip compressed. I have done:

```
gzip -f -v netEdges2017.txt
```

I have received a message in Ubuntu Terminal:

```
netEdges2017.txt:    72.6% -- replaced with netEdges2017.txt.gz
```

However, When I submit the file a receive the following message of the site:

```
The sended file (netEdges2017.txt.gz) is not gzip compressed, please compress it before to send. 
Please use the back button of your web browser.
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe that site is broken. It is several years old.

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded the C files and I was able to generate the network representation. However, I would like to know if I were doing something wrong. Using the  files I do not need to compress the input file.